# C# why does binarysearch have to be made on sorted arrays and lists?

Tags: c#

C# why does binarysearch have to be made on sorted arrays and lists?
Is there any other method that does not require me to sort the list?
It kinda messes with my program in a way that I cannot sort the list for it to work as I want to.

Comment: Think about it. Think how a binary search works. What effect would the list not being sorted have on that? Would it even work anymore?

Comment: *"It kinda messes with my program in a way that I cannot sort the list for it to work as I want to."* why can't you sort the list ?

Answer (score 2):

A binary search works by dividing the list of candidates in half using equality. Imagine the following set:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

We can also represent this as a binary tree, to make it easier to visualise:

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Now, say we want to find the number 3. We can do it like so:

1. Is 3 smaller than 8? Yes. OK, now we're looking at everything between 1 and 7.
2. Is 3 smaller than 4? Yes. OK, now we're looking at everything between 1 and 3.
3. Is 3 smaller than 2? No. OK, now we're looking at 3.
4. We found it!

Now, if your list isn't sorted, how will we divide the list in half? The simple answer is: we can't. If we swap 3 and 15 in the example above, it would work like this:

1. Is 3 smaller than 8? Yes. OK, now we're looking at everything between 1 and 7.
2. Is 3 smaller than 4? Yes. OK, now we're looking at everything between 1 and 3 (except we swapped it with 15).
3. Is 3 smaller than 2? No. OK, now we're looking at 15.
4. Huh? There's no more items to check but we didn't find it. I guess it's not in the list.

The solution is to use an appropriate data type instead. For fast lookups of key/value pairs, I'll use a Dictionary. For fast checks if something already exists, I'll use a HashSet. For general storage I'll use a List or an array.

Dictionary example:

```
var values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
values[1] = "hello";
values[2] = "goodbye";

var value2 = values[2]; // this lookup will be fast because Dictionaries are internally optimised inside and partition keys' hash codes into buckets.
```

HashSet example:

```
var mySet = new HashSet<int>();
mySet.Add(1);
mySet.Add(2);

if (mySet.Contains(2)) // this lookup is fast for the same reason as a dictionary.
{
    // do something
}
```

List exmaple:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);

if (list.Contains(2)) // this isn't fast because it has to visit each item in the list, but it works OK for small sets or places where performance isn't so important
{
}

var idx2 = list.IndexOf(2);
```

If you have multiple values with the same key, you could store a list in a Dictionary like this:

```
 var values = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

 if (!values.ContainsKey(key))
 {
    values[key] = new List<string>();
 }

 values[key].Add("value1");
 values[key].Add("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you use binary search on unordered collections. Sorting collection is the main concept of the binary search. The key is that on every move u take the middle index between l and r. On first step they are 0 and size - 1, after every step one of them becomes middle index between them. If x > arr[m] then l becomes m + 1, otherwise r becomes m - 1. Basically, on every step you take half of the array you had and, of course, it remains sorted. This code is recursive, if you don't know what recursion is(which is very important in programming), you can review and learn [here](https://code-maze.com/csharp-basics-recursion/).

```
// C# implementation of recursive Binary Search 
using System; 

class GFG { 
    // Returns index of x if it is present in 
    // arr[l..r], else return -1 
    static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int l, 
                        int r, int x) 
    { 
        if (r >= l) { 
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 

            // If the element is present at the 
            // middle itself 
            if (arr[mid] == x) 
                return mid; 

            // If element is smaller than mid, then 
            // it can only be present in left subarray 
            if (arr[mid] > x) 
                return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

            // Else the element can only be present 
            // in right subarray 
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
        } 

        // We reach here when element is not present 
        // in array 
        return -1; 
    } 

    // Driver method to test above 
    public static void Main() 
    { 

        int[] arr = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 }; 
        int n = arr.Length; 
        int x = 10; 

        int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x); 

        if (result == -1) 
            Console.WriteLine("Element not present"); 
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Element found at index "
                          + result); 
    } 
}
```

Output:
Element is present at index 3

Answer (score -1):

Sure there is.

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(42);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(54);

var index = list.IndexOf(1); //TADA!!!!
```

EDIT: Ok, I hoped the irony was obvious. But strictly speaking, if your array is not sorted, you are pretty much stuck with the linear search, readily available by means of `IndexOf()` or `IEnumerable.First()`.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica "Is there any other method that does not require me to sort the list" - yep. Linear search.

Comment: He used sarcasm but helped me solve the problem... I am just a High Schooler and thus do not know a lot about Computer Science and t he math behid it... then what are the differences between their uses? Just runtime?

Comment: @אריאלפוקסמן Yes, the difference is mainly run-time. Given a list of 3 elements, it won't matter. For 8 elements, binary search is twice as fast. For 15000 elements, it's more than 1000x faster. So yeah, _just_ runtime ;)

Comment: For 4 trillions (4 000 billions) elements, it takes 42 checks in the worst case for binary search. Binary search complexity is O(log2(N)) where N is the number of elements